# How to get items of String[] in Android

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

In my application I should get some `list` from **server** and I should show this list.
code :

```
private String[] mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings;
mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings = searchResponse.getData().getMostlyMatchedKeywordsText();
cloudChipList.clear();
fullSearchMini_chipCloud.removeAllViews();

for (int i = 0; i < mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings.length; i++) {

    cloudChipList.add(mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);
    if (i >= mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings.length - 2) {

        fullSearchMini_didYouMeanLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fullSearchMini_chipCloud.addChip(mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);
        Log.e("searchKeys", mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);

        fullSearchMini_chipCloud.setChipListener(new ChipListener() {
            @Override
            public void chipSelected(int i) {
                try {
                    Log.e("searchKeys", "new : " + mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);

                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void chipDeselected(int i) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

When show this data to user it's correct and show data, but when click on this item show me another item!

**In Logcat show me below item :**

```
searchKeys: Recep Ivedik 5
```

**But when click on this item show me another item in logcat :**

```
searchKeys: new : Recep Ivedik 3
```

For show item and click I use this code `mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]`, why in logCat show me another item when click on this item?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Move  the following line inside if block:

```
cloudChipList.add(mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings[i]);
```

Then in the method `onChipSelected()` use:

```
Log.e("searchKeys", "new : " + cloudChipList.get(i));
```

Comment: Glad I could help. ☺️

Comment: can you send to me your Skype ID?